# e.force:refreshView - Record View is not refreshed upon field update but is upon record type change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, refresh, lightning-quickaction, lightning-console

**TL;DR(edited):** We have a quick action calling a lightning component that will perform an outbound WS call from APEX, update the current record and then refresh the view.

We use the function : `workspaceAPI.refreshTab(...);`

Problem: The sub-tab record view is refreshed only if the user didn't navigate across sub-tabs on the Lightning Service Console.
Technically, if the user navigates across tabs and sub-tabs, the workspaceAPI  becomes undefined.

**Questions (edited):**

- The workspaceAPI is supposed to be friendly with the Lightning Console. Am I missing something to handle subtabs ?
- The native JS 'location.reload()' function works as a workaround but is a disgusting solution (the whole page being reloaded with the splash screen). Would you suggest an other one ?
- As 'location.reload()' seems the only workaround. I went for a hybrid solution figuring out if we can refresh cleanly (force:refreshview) or do the dirty refresh in case of error. Would you suggest an other out-of-the-box solution ?

Thanks in advance,

**Details:**

- Lightning component embedded in a quickAction on the page layout called upon pressing the button
- The refresh part in the Helper:

  ```
      actionOr.setCallback(this, function (a) {

          var messageType = '';

          if (a.getReturnValue() == "someStuff1")
              messageType = 'info';
          else if (a.getReturnValue() == "Somestuff2")
              messageType = 'success';
          else
              messageType = 'error';

          toastEvent.setParams({
              mode: 'dismissible',
              type: messageType,
              title : 'Simple Title',
              message: a.getReturnValue()
          });
          toastEvent.fire();
                  component.find("workspace").getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
                      $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                      component.find('subProcRecord').reloadRecord();
                      var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
                      workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                          tabId: focusedTabId,
                          includeAllSubtabs: true
                      });
                  }).catch(function (error) {
                      console.log('Error is : ' + error);
                      location.reload();

                  });
          var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
          dismissActionPanel.fire();                

      });

      $A.enqueueAction(actionOr);
  ```
- The target browser is : Firefox ESR 52.8.1
- We are using Lightning Console
- We declared the workspaceAPI in the cmp : `<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />`

Comment: a server side apex will not trigger anything on your component, you should wait for the apex method to come back and then trigger the refresh. also you are using a standard refresh (`$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");`) this will trigger refresh only to standard components that listen to it, or to your custom component - if you implement a listener to it

Comment: @ItaiShmida : The issue is a bit trickier actually : it comes from tab and sub-tab switching in the Lightning Service Console which makes the refresh event fail. I transformed the code to use the workspaceAPI but I'm still getting issues upon tabs and subtabs swapping. Other than that, I'm already in a callback so I'm already waiting for the apex method to come back...